# Using easy-ssl-acceptor in LispWorks

Tags: ssl, lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot, lispworks

I want to use Hunchentoot's `easy-ssl-acceptor` in LispWorks. However, I see that this class of acceptor has the following feature syntax `#-:hunchentoot-no-ssl`.

This feature is indeed present in my `*features*` list, so I cannot use this class. What is the problem here? Why was `:hunchentoot-no-ssl` added to my `*features*`? How can I resolve this so that I can use the `easy-ssl-acceptor` class?

PS: I am on macOS 10.13 using LispWorks 7.1.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Could you also give the version of Hunchentoot as provided by "hunchentoot.asd", and/or the steps you use to load the system? With version "1.2.38", it seems the feature is not added automatically (searching files with "ag hunchentoot-no-ssl").

Comment: I have Hunchentoot v1.2.38, loaded through Quicklisp.

Comment: It is hard to reproduce for me (different environment). Can you observe this all the time, when starting from a fresh Lispworks? Do you need to install libssl?

Comment: @coredump The feature `:hunchentoot-no-ssl` is present in the `*features*` list as soon as I start LispWorks. I have openssl installed.

Comment: If it is present when you start Lispworks and nothing else, maybe you can investigate at which point it is added by disabling user init files, or system init files (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/LW/html/lw-484.htm). You can also clear the compiled files in `asdf::*user-cache*` and try recompiling. This is a bit tedious I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear how this feature got into your `*features*`, but the simplest thing to do in this case is to remove it from `*features*` manually and then force-rebuild Hunchentoot:

```
* (alexandria:removef *features* :hunchentoot-no-ssl)
* (asdf:load-system :hunchentoot :force t)
```